# Adding node attributes that are in an R dataframe to an igraph network object

Tags: r, igraph

I have created a network object using igraph and now I would like to add the node attributes.
The nodes attributes are in a dataframe.  My initial code to set up the network/graph is here:

```
library(igraph)
just_edges  <- data.frame(
  edge_data.to = c(64L, 65L, 67L, 191L, 215L, 116L), 
  edge_data.from = c(59L, 60L, 64L, 86L, 86L, 103L)
)
initial.net = graph.data.frame(just_edges,directed = FALSE)
```

I would like to add to the Status.Day1, Status.Day2, Status.Day3, and so on from this dataframe, and I would like for them to be the node attributes:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  Ids = 1426:1431, 
  Grade.and.Class = c("5B", "5B", "5B", "5B", "5B", "5B"), 
  color = c("darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray"), 
  onset = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  terminus = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf), 
  newid = 1:6, 
  Status.Day1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
  Status.Day2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
  Status.Day3 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
  Status.Day4 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  Status.Day5 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
  Status.Day6 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
  Status.Day7 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
  Status.Day8 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
  Status.Day9 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
  Status.Day10 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
```

Let me know if any other information would be useful.

Comment: We don't have `just_edges` so we can't make your graph.

Comment: @G5W I have added that now

Comment: Thanks Natalie,  but your graph has 10 nodes and your attributes have only 6 values each. Did you mean for these to be _edge_ attributes?

Comment: Hmmm... That is just the header for the dataframes.  If different/more info would be helpful just let me know.  I am not very good yet at what to provide/how to provide it on here yet.  My graph has 242 nodes and 1556 edges.  I definitely don't want edge attributes, I would like node attributes.

Comment: Then you need the same number of  values for each attribute as nodes.

Comment: There is an Ids column in your data frame. Are these ids node id's?

Comment: yes, the IDs for the nodes are in the column, node_data$newid

Comment: But none of those values in the new data match the names in `just_edges`. Your first row in `just_edges` connects node 59 to node 64. And you have a total of 10 distinct node names. It's unclear how you want to match these datasets up. If the numbers and order matched, you could do something like `vertex_attr(initial.net) <- dd`

Comment: They do, I think it is just because of the values showing in each for the first few rows.

Comment: just_edges$to and just_edges$from have the IDs for the edge data and node_data$newid is for the Ids in the node dataframe.  They match, you just can't see it

Comment: If you run `V(initial.net)` you will see all the node/vertex names in your graph object.  And `E(initial.net)` lists all the edges. The data you have provided does not seem to be reproducible. Why not start with a smaller subset you create by hand that makes it clear what you are trying to do rather than subsetting existing data.

Comment: this might be useful https://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html

Comment: Hello everyone - I answered a similar question over here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852237/r-creating-a-statnet-network-with-node-attributes  is the answer I gave here correct?